# How to check if polygon in one table intersect with point and radius from second table?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

How can I check if polygon in one table intersect with point and radius from second table ?

- first table we have field (name: `area`) ,type `geometry` which contains `polygon`.
- second table we have 2 fields:

  - field (name: `pt`) ,type: `geometry` which contains `point`
  - field (name: `radius`) ,type: `int`

The geometry values in **WKB** format

I want to check if the polygon intersect with the circle (point + radius).

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) function to find the distance between the polygon and the point. If the distance between them is less than the radius, then the polygon would intersect with a circle around the point with that radius.

Example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM polygon_table, circle_table
WHERE ST_Distance(polygon_table.area, circle_table.pt) <= circle_table.radius;
```

Comment: Does the radius need to be converted to meters ? cm ?

Comment: It needs to match (or be converted to) the same units as the geometries.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ST_Contains`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) to check if the point is inside of the polygon and then calculate the buffer around your point and see if they intersect, with [`ST_Buffer`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) and [`ST_Intersects`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) respectively. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM polygon_table t1, circle_table t2
WHERE 
  ST_Contains(t1.area, t2.pt) AND 
  ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(t2.pt,t2.radius),t1.area)
```

Note: the buffer will be created using the unit of your SRS. For instance, if you're using WGS84 it will be in degrees. If you want it in metres instead, use `geography` instead of `geometry` or simply cast it in real time, e.g. `t1.area::geography`.